# Extract CSS in NUXTjs generate

Tags: css, webpack, nuxt.js, generate

When using `nuxt generate` I am generating various HTML pages that happen to be about 300 kB in size. Majority of the file is CSS style placed inline to it. Is it a way to put it in an external file and reduce size of HTML ?

Comment: Define what you mean by *placed inline to it*, do you mean in the .vue files in the `<style>` tag? Or do you mean inline in the traditional sense? Google, `extractCSS: true` which is most likely the option your after.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can extract the CSS in the main chunk into a separate CSS file using

*nuxt.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    extractCSS: true
  }
}
```

This is documented [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/)

If you want to import css files globally use

```
module.exports = {
  css: [
    // Load a Node.js module directly (here it's a Sass file)
    'bulma',
    // CSS file in the project
    '@/assets/css/main.css',
    // SCSS file in the project
    '@/assets/css/main.scss'
  ]
}
```

as documented [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css)